# Is there any 3rd party Floating Toolbar out there?

Tags: delphi

I'm looking for a toobar that's stay hide until the context be needed and when it happens (ie.: the mouse is over a given field) the toolbar appears floating right "on" the fucused control, like MS Word 2007 does when the user point the mouse cursor over selected text.

Answer (score 3):

Toolbar2000 is a classic toolbar solution (floating and docking) for Delphi. You will find it at http://www.jrsoftware.org/tb2k.php. While the initial install might look a bit dated, you can "skin it" using packages like TBX (http://www.indasoftware.com/tbx/).

Comment: Have a look at [SpTBXLib](http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/index.htm) too, which also is an extension of Toolbar2000.

Comment: Thanks Jon, my bad if I wasn't enough clearly. I'm looking for a toobar that's stay hide until the context be needed and when it happens (ie.: the mouse is over a given field) the toolbar appears floating right "on" the fucused control)

Comment: @Gedean: you might want to append the clarification to your question. I'm also interested in answers to this one. My first guess would be to put any toolbar on a borderless form (with the title bar removed), so that it fills the entire area of the form.